# Word for "seeing without being seen"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for *seeing without being seen*? I want to write about those on the advantageous side of tinted glasses. *Visual/optical eavesdropping* is the closest phrase I can think of.

Comment: Perhaps the downvote was because this is a simple matter of General Reference, which is offtopic and a reason for closing according to the FAQ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try covert, as in covert surveillance, or in your example, a covert observer.

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably go with [**spying**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spying):

> to watch secretly usually for hostile purposes

Comment: thanks. I'd like a more neutral word though.

Answer (score 2):

Does *[incognito](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incognito)* work for your purposes?

> : with one's identity concealed

Answer (score 2):

No single word comes to mind, but, if this for journalism, a short phrase might be as good as, or better than, a single word (which would probably be some latinate obscurity).  How about *discreetly observing/watching/gazing/...*?

> With reflective lenses, you can reflect on the world that you're reflecting back, gazing discreetly while dressing chicly, grabbing a eager eyeful without risking an irate earful.

Answer (score 0):

"Observe unobserved"

"covertly spy on"

"covertly observe"

"covertly watch"

"voyeur" - implies fetishness or at least and wierdo

Answer (score -2):

Of course there's [invisible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/invisible).

> Out of the field of vision of a person.
>   Covered by another object.
>   In the dark.
>   That is perfectly camouflaged.