# Is there a visual equivalent of the word "overhear"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I love the word overhear. I often want to communicate a similar concept, but visually - with somebody looking over my shoulder at my computer screen, for example.

"My husband (overheard) me shopping for his birthday present" - except if he used his eyes, not his ears.

"Oversee" obviously means something completely unrelated. So does there exist a word that means what I want?

Comment: I'd look at things like "spotted", "glimpsed", "caught sight of" etc.

Comment: Eavesdrop; secretly listen. Not exactly what you wanted since it is intentional.

Comment: related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71293/word-for-seeing-without-being-seen

Comment: The husband caught a glimpse, or sight, of her shopping. Funny how the definitions of so many suggestions on this page use these exact words, yet no answer actually suggests using these exact words.

Comment: "I happened to see him buying my present"... though it isn't one word

Comment: Chanced upon is what you are asking.

Comment: My typing the memo had caught Jims sight.  Jim chanced upon me typing the memo.Jim witnessed the memo being typed.

Comment: Maybe the reason there's no exact visual equivalent is that there's no exact physical equivalent. If you're close by, you can't stop yourself from hearing something (without clapping your hands over your ears) but observing something is more of an active thing.

Comment: accidental peek?

Answer (score 40):

I think ***[glimpse](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glimpse)***   is close to the meaning you are looking for:

> - (tr) to catch sight of briefly or momentarily.

(AHD)

Comment: +1 this is good because it implies it is accidental. The only slight limitation is that glimpse implies it is momentary, whereas you can "overhear" an entire conversation. But I guess if you glimpse and *don't* look away, it's no longer accidental (unlike overhearing), so you'd need another word anyway (something like "My husband glimpsed me shopping for his birthday present. He tried to act like he hadn't seen anything, but he kept spying to see what it was")

Answer (score 32):

Espy

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/espy

"To catch sight of; to perceive with the eyes; to discover, as a distant object partly concealed, or not obvious to notice; to see at a glance; to discern unexpectedly"

Overheard implies not directed at or intended for the hearer.
Espy should carry the same implication. Standing behind someone staring at the computer screen is not espying, but opening the door and seeing something on their computer screen is espying.

Answer (score 11):

Based on the context you gave above for the term *"overhear"*, I think that a decent definition for what you are looking for is simply ***spy***. Apart from the obvious James Bond noun, it has a couple of alternative verb definitions, [Dictionary.com defines as](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spy):

1. to discover or find out by observation or scrutiny
2. to observe (a person, place, enemy, etc.) secretively or furtively with hostile intent.
3. to inspect or examine or to search or look for closely or carefully.

Comment: overhear is accidental.  spy is quite deliberately.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen thats not quite true. To overhear is to listen without the speaker's knowledge, and isn't necessarily accidental. See TheFreeDictionary's definition of overhear (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overhear). In Alex Ryan's question, it's conceivable that the husband could have been listening furtively, and not necessarily accidentally.

Comment: Using "spy" or "espy" requires care to avoid the common / default connotation of intentional spying, rather than the accidentally-notice sense.

Answer (score 10):

The verb to **oversee** actually has this exact meaning; [see](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oversee):

> **oversee** *verb* -sees -seeing -saw or -seen (transitive)*
>
> 2. to watch secretly or accidentally

Comment: The verb *oversee* does not have a normal meaning of the visual equivalent of "overhear". In common usage it means to supervise, manage, or monitor - and only that. The roughly equivalent terms could be "spotted" - or "spied" if it were deliberate. However in most contexts the simple "saw" will be understood to mean the equivalent of "overheard".

Comment: Maybe. Excerpt that there are sources that recognize such usage. [Another reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oversee).

Comment: There may well be sources that cite such a possible usage, but are there any real-world examples where the word is used in such a sense? I've never seen one, but am willing to be enlightened.

Comment: Not going to downvote because you've cited legitimate sources, but I agree with Cargill - this is not common usage and would likely be misunderstood.

Comment: @Cargill That's a Austin to HarperCollins. They are in this business.

Comment: Perhaps they are in the wrong business ... I have not seen "oversee" used to mean the visual equivalent of "overhear".

Comment: Googling "accidentally oversaw" does in fact return results. Even in books.

Comment: The use of 'oversee' in the sense "To catch sight of, glimpse; to observe secretly, spy on" (OED) is well-established, with example quotes from Fielding in 1735 to the Guardian in 1995. I'm just embarrassed I overlooked the possibility.

Comment: @macraf: to "accidentally oversee" can also mean to accidentally _fail_ to see something, so the opposite of what he wants.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich *Oversee* as a synonym of *overlook*...?

Comment: @macraf  "Accidentally oversaw" would be fine, since it stresses the accidental nature, but "oversaw" on its own -- while it may have an official definition and citeable uses as accidental -- would imply its supervisory meaning (perhaps unless the context clearly indicated otherwise).

Comment: @macraf: yes, when I Google "accidentally oversaw" I see many uses like that. It's also perfectly normal chess jargon for failing to notice an opponent's move, which is why I know it, but the search shows it's a lot broader.

Comment: Writing *"oversaw"* in quotes would probably convey the unconventional usage of the word.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid I can't think of a single-word equivalent for overhear.  Common usage would be to say, "**I just happened to see**...".  This commonly happens when someone **glances** in your direction and "**catches sight of**" the object/event you are referring to.

Comment: Also 'noticed' or 'happened to notice'-- meaning happened to see (if it's implicitly visual information, such as a document) without the intent of specifically looking for it.

Answer (score 7):

Consider, ***catch***.

*I caught her shopping the other day*

*My husband caught me shopping for his birthday present*

> catch
>
> a. discover unexpectedly : find
>
> b. become suddenly aware of  [M-W](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch)

Comment: +1 This is the first word that I thought of, even though it isn't explicitly visual.

Comment: "Catch" implies that there was some follow-up action though - "My husband caught me shopping for his birthday present" isn't great for situation equivalent to accidental overhearing where he glimpsed the shopping then said and did nothing, you'd expect he, at least, blurted out some comment. **"Catch sight of"** works, however

Answer (score 6):

One might say, "I saw it in the corner of my eye." Or you "saw it from the corner of your eye."

Not a perfect match, but worth mentioning.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of-from-the-corner-of-your-eye

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+the+corner+of+eye

Answer (score 5):

I would say "I witnessed", which in my mind means something like "I saw it by accident" or "I saw it happen".

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to say ***no, there isn’t.***

I cannot think of any, and I do not think any of the existing answers provides a good alternative. Sometimes there just isn’t a good word for what you want, and I think this is one of them.

Impossible to prove a negative, of course, but I’m leaving this here for people to vote on if they agree/disagree.

Answer (score 0):

The 'fly-on-the-wall' phrase might work for you:

> My husband was *the fly on the wall* when I was shopping for his birthday present.

For a single word, I don't think anybody has mentioned the venerable slang, 'twig':

> **twig**, *v*
>   *slang or colloq.*
>   1. trans.To become aware of by seeing; to perceive, discern, catch sight of; to recognize.

["twig, v.4". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/208051 (accessed December 10, 2015).]

In your example, this might become

> My husband **twigged** what I was looking at when I was shopping for his birthday present.

Comment: Fly on the wall doesn't sound right in this context. I've tied to work out why, and I think it's because it's an expression used to describe what someone would like to be, e.g. 'I wish I'd been a fly on the wall at that conversation!' I can't think of any situation where you would use it to describe something that is actually happening. Similarly, this definition comes closer to the meaning of twig that I'm familiar with, as an English speaker http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/twig. The key is it's something suddenly worked out, like a puzzle, or something that's not obvious.

Comment: @JoeMiller - Fly on the wall can definitely be used in real situations, in fact there's a whole genre called "fly-on-the-wall documentaries". The reason (for me) that it doesn't work in the OP's context is that it is *deliberate*, not *accidental*.

Answer (score 0):

For

> somebody looking over my shoulder at my computer screen, for example

The expression would be **shoulder surfing**.

> The practice of spying on the user of a cash-dispensing machine or other electronic device in order to obtain their personal identification number, password, etc.
>
> Example sentences
>
> Bushell believes suggestions that chip and PIN will lead to an increase in shoulder-surfing and street robbery is ridiculous scaremongering.
>
> Provided that these brain signals can be recorded and processed in an accurate and repeatable way, a pass-thought system might provide a quasi two-factor, changeable, authentication method resistant to shoulder-surfing.

Source http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/shoulder-surfing

Answer (score 0):

Would **"eavesdrop on"** work?  If you seek literary antecedents, there's Roman playwright Plautus' "Braggart Soldier" (based on an ancient Greek original) where a slave, who's chasing a monkey on the roof, *sees* something no one wants him to see, thus setting in motion the farce.

Answer (score -2):

I would say simply "watched" or "gazed" would be equivalent words, obviously not carrying the same value as "overheard" but just as representative of the action.